# Disable Bluetooth sound output

Tags: java, android, audio, bluetooth

I am writing an app which monitors the volume setting of the notification stream (using a broadcast receiver for `android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION` - kind of a hack I know) and when it is set to silent I would like to stop my Bluetooth headset from ringing but without disconnecting it, so that if I choose to answer the call (it vibrates or I see it ringing) I can do so from my Bluetooth headset.

So far I've tried muting the voice stream, the Bluetooth stream (by providing the `int 6`), setting `setBluetoothScoOn(false)`, using `stopBluetoothSco()` and muting the previously mentioned streams but nothing seems to work.  I've got the modify audio permission so I'm beginning to think it isn't possible.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When connected on bluetooth headset, call notifications are send using HFP protocol , this protocol only internally sends certain AT commands(phone to headset) which lets headset know about the call , settings  SCO ON/OFF will turn call audio to headset/phone, ringing is internal to bluetooth headset